# How to keep selected value in dropdownlist selected after click submit button in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selected

In my View I have this dropdownlist that returns data from database:

```
@Html.DropDownList("somevalue", (SelectList) ViewBag.DropList, "--Select Customer--", Model.Search.SomeValue)
```

But after I click search button:

```
<input class="first-search_btn" type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

Operation is executed, but value from dropdown list returns to first empty value "Select Customer". How can I keep selected value from dropdownlist after I click "Search".

Comment: in post action get selected value and populate ``selectlist`` again and set in ``ViewBag.DropList``

Answer (score 1):

Try to use use DropDownListFor like I did:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SubscriptionTypeId, new SelectList(ViewBag.SubscriptionTypes, "Key", "Value", Model.SubscriptionTypeId), new{ @class = "w100" })
```

where Model.SubscriptionTypeId is default selected value
and

```
ViewBag.SubscriptionTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SubscriptionTypeDefinition)).Cast<SubscriptionTypeDefinition>().ToDictionary(item => (int)item, item => item.ToLocalizedString());
```